# How can i create an array in defined order as below?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

The array in this order:

[image: Array is in this order]

I want to create a new array as:

[image: Want new array in this order]

Comment: This is basic [map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). iterate your array and transform it.

Comment: Just a helpful suggestion; instead of posting screen shots, you should put the code into the actual comment and code block so we can copy/paste and work on it if needed.

Comment: Btw, your desired output has no **date**.. are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: seroiusly, who is upvoting these?

Comment: Thanks @AttemptedMastery. I will take care of that from next time. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Yes I am sure I need in the similar format. I couldn't post the original data but i want similar output. @vsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function on your data to get your desired output like you posted above. According to question, a possible solution would be as below

```js
const data = [{
    "date": "2020-01-01",
    "point": {
      "a": "1",
      "b": "2"
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-02-01",
    "point": {
      "a": "3",
      "b": "4"
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-03-01",
    "point": {
      "a": "5",
      "b": "6"
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-04-01",
    "point": {
      "a": "7",
      "b": "8"
    }
  }
];
const res = data.map((_, index) => {
  return {
    series: {
      data: data.slice(0, index + 1).map(i => [Number(i.point.a), Number(i.point.b)])
    }
  }
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
resultArray = yourarray.map(function(data){
    return {
        series:{
            "data":[data.points.a,data.points.b]
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i have tried this and got the output as: `{
        series: {
            data: [[1, 2]]
        }
    },
    {
        series: {
            data: [[3,4]]
        }
    },
    {
        series: {
            data: [[5, 6 ]]
        }
    },`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will get you what you want:

```
const orig = [
            {
                "date": "2020-01-01",
                "point": {
                    "a": "1",
                    "b": "2"
                }
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-02-01",
                "point": {
                    "a": "3",
                    "b": "4"
                }
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-03-01",
                "point": {
                    "a": "5",
                    "b": "6"
                }
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-04-01",
                "point": {
                    "a": "7",
                    "b": "8"
                }
            }
        ];

        // Make the new array.
        const points = [];
        const newArray = orig.map( x => {

            points.push([x.point.a, x.point.b]);
            return {
                "series": {
                    "data": points.slice(0)
                }
            }

        });

        // Log the new array.
        console.log(newArray);
```